# Why cant this specific delete statment remove this row im my SQL Database

Tags: python, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to perfect this `SQL` delete statement for `Python`, where currently I want to just delete this row so I can get the formatting right. However the row just isn't being deleted. Could I have some friendly feedback on why it isn't being removed.

I call my function like this:-

```
self.DeleteOrderFromBook("Admin", "0", "100", "50", "2021-02-26 20:29:39.297658")

        
def DeleteOrderFromBook(self,Name,BuyOrSell,Amount,Price,Time):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("Books.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        fml = "DELETE FROM TraidingBook WHERE Username='{0}' AND BuyOrSell='{1}' AND Amount='{2}' AND Price='{3}' AND TimeStamp='{4}';".format(Name,BuyOrSell,Amount,Price,Time)
        print(fml)
        c.execute(fml)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

That is the python function for making the string.

```
DELETE FROM TraidingBook 
WHERE Username='Admin' 
  AND BuyOrSell='0' 
  AND Amount='100' 
  AND Price='50' 
  AND TimeStamp='2021-02-26 20:29:39.297658';
```

However this line in the `Database` still exists -

```
 ('Admin', 0, 100, 50, '2021-02-26 20:29:39.297658')
```

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Is the table name correct — "TraidingBook"? I ask because there seems to be a typo. Also, you should consider using the parameter form of the `c.execute` function as it handles special characters automatically.

Comment: Do not use string formatting to pass values to SQL queries. You risk SQL injection, and issues in general. Use your DB library's placeholders. In case of SQLite the placeholders are `?`.

Comment: How are you testing that the result has not been deleted? Are you checking for the return value or are you looking in the database? If the latter, it's possible that the client has cached the table values and you need to make it refresh the cache.

Comment: @Alan im storing it as a file and then printing a select all

Comment: @Ali thank you for pointing out the obvious, I had slipped an extra I in the table name. Its been a long afternoon ha. Many Thanks

Comment: BuyOrSell, Ammount (which is also misspelled) and Price are all integer fields.  Do not quote them.